# How to create a known amount array of objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created three java classes, and in the main Java file I created three instances of one of my classes, let's call it `Television.java`. I was told to transform this to 8 instances, but to structure them in an object along with all my methods. Every time I try to do it with a for-loop to have my object instance as an array, it forces my console to write each element name, which is not what I want to achieve.

```java
Television[] tv = new Television[8];

public static void watchProgram(){
    for(int i = 0; I < tv.length; i++){
        System.out.println("User" + tv[i] + " is currently watching television");
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to Java, but this is something I need to fix by today.

Thank you.

Comment: you have used `I` instead of `i` in for loop, rest let me check

Comment: Please be a bit specific and give the complete code.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide some example of what you expect the output to be

Comment: you have initialized the array, however assigment code to the television object is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Do initialisation of objects

```
public static void watchProgram(){
    for(int i = 0; i < tv.length; i++){
        tv[i]=new Television(); // initialise Television object
        System.out.println("User" + tv[i] + " is currently watching television");
    }
}
```